# Jupyter Lab in Pipenv does not load venv package paths

Tags: pip, jupyter, jupyter-lab, pipenv

I'm using macOS Catalina

I cannot load modules from Jupyter Lab in Pipenv environment.
I use pyenv & pipenv at the same time.

```
pipenv --python=3.7.4
pipenv shell
pipenv install jupyter lab numpy
jupyter lab
```

and

```
import numpy as np
```

then I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'` .

It solves with this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/myname/.local/share/virtualenvs/0429-n7nIDzhY/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
# comes from `pip show numpy`
```

The problem is that `sys.path` does not include the venv package path.
Does anyone have the same issue?
No problem with Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

It solved with

```
ipython kernel install --user --name=<project_name>
```

and select the kernel in Jupyter Lab.

But I wonder why I did not need such operation with Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Can't I set the kernel to default kernel of Jupyter Lab?